# What should go into file.def and what into file.bbx?

Tags: biblatex, best-practices, bibliographystyle

My biblatex styles bundle consists of a standard.bbx file and some .bbx, .cbx, .dbx and .lbx files (the bundle provides different citation styles; therefore standard.bbx contains common code of the bibliography styles).

The best practice involves the presence of a .def file, but analyzing `biblatex` package and other biblatex styles I'm having a hard time figuring out what would be right to include into the .def file.

I'm aware that for the proper functioning of my biblatex styles this issue is irrelevant and, theoretically, I might as well write the entire content of standard.bbx in a .def file. However, I would like to keep the code as neat as possible.

Currently the contents of my standard.bbx file are as follows:

- Definition of warning and error messages
- Dynamic sourcemapping (\DeclareStyleSourcemap)
- Declarationd of toggle (\newtoggle) and options (\DeclareBibliographyOption)
- Execution of global options (\ExecuteBibliographyOptions)
- Redefinition of punctuation, strings and fields formatting
- Definition of boolean conditionals (\def\if[foo])
- Definition of commands
- Definition of new bibmacro (\newbibmacro)
- Redefinition of bibmacro (\renewbibmacro)
- Declaration of bibliography driver (\DeclareBibliographyDriver)
- Definition of bibcheck (\defbibcheck)
- Definition of sorting template (\DeclareSortingTemplate)
- Use of \DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix
- Use of \NewBibliographyString
- Definition of new bibenvironment (\defbibenvironment)

Which of the above items could reasonably fit into a .def file?

Comment: Just wondering, what you are doing? As an average user you don’t need to know all that.

Comment: bbx is for the bibliography style, cbx for the citation style , lbx for language settings. Generally they should be self contained, that means a cbx should be loadable even if the bbx is not used.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I know the difference between .bbx, .cbx, .dbx, and .lbx files.  But since some biblatex styles also include a .def file (e.g., biblatex-gost, biblatex-sbl) I wanted to understand - not abstractly - what elements of my standard.bbx file (see list above) should be moved to a .def file. I would like to write neat code, following best practices... that's all.

Answer (score 2):

The structural constraints that `biblatex` imposes on `biblatex` styles do not include a `.def` file.

- You need a `.bbx` file for the bibliography style and a `.cbx` file for the citation style. (At least in theory the idea is that you can neatly separate bibliography and citation bibmacros etc. with those two files and that users might have the chance to load different bibliography and citation styles. In practice it is not always clear if a certain macro should go into the `.bbx` or `.cbx` file and some styles are so complex that it is next to impossible to untangle the definitions, so that they only work if both the `.bbx` and `.cbx` are loaded.)
- If you need to modify the default data model, you need a `.dbx` file.
- If your style needs localisation that goes beyond that of standard `biblatex` or you need to modify the localisation of standard `biblatex`, you'll also include `.lbx` files.

All of those files are loaded via `biblatex`, its options and other features.
If you want your style to include additional files of different type, you need to load those yourself. (The styles in my `biblatex-ext` bundle which has a `ext-biblatex-aux.def` all have a line that explicitly loads that file.)

I would argue that best practices do not dictate that you should have a `.def` file. Some more complex styles do and benefit from it in some way. But there is plenty of solid styles that don't.

---

For `biblatex-ext` I used a `.def` file to define auxiliary commands and backwards compatibility code that I felt would not have fitted cleanly into the `.bbx` or `.cbx` files.

Since standard `biblatex` has a `.def` file (`biblatex.def`) that defines some more generic "building block macros", some authors of more complex styles might feel inclined to follow that practice and provide definitions there that make sense for both the bibliography and citation style. (Do note though that core `biblatex` is obviously a special case: `biblatex.def` is always loaded automatically. It makes sense to provide some helpful bibmacros in a way that makes sure that they are always defined even without loading a core style. The `.def`s of other styles need to be loaded explicitly by those styles.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand the difficulty in responding, as this also presupposes personal assessments and opinions.

Comment: 1) I know how biblatex loads its own .def file (via the command \blx@inputonce in biblatex.sty); 2) I know that a .def file must be loaded explicitly (again via the \blx@inputonce command). I will now better analyze my needs and try to understand the usefulness or otherwise of creating a .def file in my bundle.